# Difference between branch forcing and hard resetting

Tags: git

The title is pretty explicit. Say I'm on main with a few commits and I want to go back one commit on main. Both these commands work :

```
$ git branch -f main HEAD^
$ git reset --hard HEAD^
```

What differences will there be when using one or the other ? Is there one to favor ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of *branch name movement*, these would be the same, if `git branch -f main HEAD^` were allowed while on branch `main`.  But it's not:

```
$ cd ~/tmp && mkdir ttt && git init
Initialized empty Git repository in ...
$ echo test branch -f > README && git add README && git commit -m initial
[master (root-commit) 23903eb] initial
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 README
$ git commit --allow-empty -m c2
[master 14290a1] c2
$ git branch other
$ git branch -m main
$ git branch
* main
  other
$ git branch -f main HEAD^
fatal: Cannot force update the current branch.
```

So, as you can see, we're literally *forced* to use `git reset`, not `git branch -f`, when we're on the branch in question.<sup>1</sup>

That said, the `git reset` command—when used in this fashion—does *up to three things:*

1. It moves the *current branch name* (if `HEAD` is attached; in detached-HEAD mode, it moves the detached HEAD instead).
2. Then, if not prevented with `--soft`, it resets the index / staging-area: the current, i.e., `HEAD`, commit's contents replace the old index contents.
3. Then, if told to do so with `--hard`, it resets the working tree.  This step actually happens "at the same time as" step 2 since what-to-reset is only known by the old index content, but aside from this implementation detail, it's usually best to think of this as the third optional step.

This all has to do with the rather peculiar fact that `HEAD`, in Git, is normally a *symbolic name*, "attached to" the *current branch name*, and that in the fresh checkout / switch state, there are *three copies of each file:*

1. The `HEAD`-commit copy exists, and is completely read-only.  Nothing you do will ever change it.  (You can change which *commit* `HEAD` names, of course.)
2. Git's index contains a copy of every file, copied out of the current commit.<sup>2</sup>
3. Your working tree contains a *usable* (de-Git-ified, no longer compressed and read-only and hence unusable) copy of the file.  This is the one you see and work with, despite the existence of the other copies (or "copies").

Note that the first two copies *are* in Git.  They are therefore available forever, or at least, as long as you don't use `git reset` or `git branch -f` to make the commits themselves (eventually) die off.  The *third* copy, however, is *not* in Git.  If anything wrecks them, Git cannot help you with that.

Since, by definition, the branch name stored in `HEAD` *is* the *current* branch name, `git reset` can get us back to that happy state—all three copies matching—if we use `--hard`.<sup>3</sup>  But `git branch -f` can't, so we're forbidden from using it.  If some bug slips up and *does* let us use it, we get the effect of `git reset --soft`, since `git branch` does not update index or working tree.

---

<sup>1</sup>This *should* apply to added work-trees as well, but historically there have been bugs in this area.  Whether your Git version allows it may depend on your Git version.

<sup>2</sup>The index copy is in Git's internal, read-only, compressed and de-duplicated form.  Since by definition a copy that was made *from* the copy that's *in the commit* is identical to the copy that is in the commit, everything in the index is de-duplicated, and therefore takes no space (apart from the index entry itself).  So calling this a "copy" is slightly misleading—but unlike the *committed* version, the index copy *can be replaced or removed*, with a simple `git add` or `git rm` for instance.

The `git add` variant compresses a working tree copy, checks to see if it's a duplicate, and then either puts a new, never-before-seen version in as the index entry, or uses the existing duplicate version as the index entry.  The `git rm` version simply removes the index entry entirely.  As the index entry is really, internally, a *reference to* the Git-ified read-only-and-de-duplicated copy, the Git-ified copy itself remains intact if necessary (if existing commits are sharing it).

<sup>3</sup>While I call it a "happy state" here, if you had unsaved changes in your working tree, that you spent a long time working on, *you* might be rather un-happy.  The happiness here may be Git's alone.